# Host in house attendance system

Tags: hosting

Currently my office has an attendance system which is built with PHP, MySQL.
Currently it's hosted in-house and when an employee come to office they can check-in, check-out.
How should I give access to employees who are working at home?
They should be able to check-in, check-out while working at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem statement. Your current system is hosted on on-premise and you want to expose it to publically or access securely.

There could be two possible solution-

1. Give your employees VPN client and setup VPN. (More secure)
2. Expose application publically

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Could you explain little bit about 2nd option "Expose application publicly".

Comment: you can use http tunnelling as well for this to solve

Comment: have a look ngrok for short term resolution